# MySQL query for timestamp of change in column value

Tags: mysql, sql, min

How can I query dates to when a specific column value changes for a given id? The table below shows the dates when a job is ran to identify the status for the `oppid`. I want to track when the `oppid` has `status` = status_1 to show the date earliest date when the status is set and the date when the status is <> status_1.

```
| oppid  |    date   |  status   |
+--------+  ---------+-----------+
| 1000   | 2020-07-01|  status_1 |
| 1000   | 2020-07-02|  status_1 |
| 1000   | 2020-07-03|  status_1 |
| 1000   | 2020-07-04|  status_2 |
| 1000   | 2020-07-07|  status_2 |
| 1000   | 2020-07-15|  status_1 |
| 1000   | 2020-07-16|  status_1 |
| 1001   | 2020-07-10|  status_1 |
| 1001   | 2020-07-11|  status_1 |
| 1000   | 2020-08-01|  status_2 |
```

Desired outcome to look something like the below:

```
| oppid  |   status  |  status_set | status_changed |
+--------+  ---------+-------------+----------------+
| 1000   | status_1  |  2020-07-01 |   2020-07-04   |
| 1000   | status_1  |  2020-07-15 |   2020-08-01   |
| 1001   | status_1  |  2020-07-10 |                |
```

Comment: which version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select oppid, status, date as status_set, status_changed
from (select t.*,
             lag(status) over (partition by oppid order by date) as prev_status,
             min(case when status <> 'status_1' then date end) over (partition by oppid order by date desc) as status_changed
      from t
     ) t
where (prev_status is null or prev_status <> status) and
      status = 'status_1';
```

The previous status is used for filtering to find each time that the status becomes `'status_1'`.  The `min()` is used to get the next date when the status is not `'status_1'`.